# Pandas Delete Part of String

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df
                       Time
    5/10/2017 (135) 01:05:03
    5/11/2017 (136) 04:05:06
```

Given an input date such as this in a DataFrame, how would I delete the Julian Date, (135) and (136), and remove the whitespace in the middle, so that the output looks like:

```
>>> df
                       Time
    5/10/2017 01:05:03
    5/11/2017 04:05:06
```

I've tried:

```
df['Time'].replace('(135)','', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

which outputs:

```
>>> df
                    Time
0  5/10/2017 () 01:05:03
```

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by regex:

First need escape `()` by `\` because special chars in regex, then match all ints by `\d+` and last match zero or more whitespaces after `)` by `\s*`.

---

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.replace("\(\d+\)\s*", '')
print (df)
                 Time
0  5/10/2017 01:05:03
1  5/11/2017 04:05:06
```

And if need convert to datetime:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'].str.replace("\(\d+\)\s*", ''))
print (df)
                 Time
0 2017-05-10 01:05:03
1 2017-05-11 04:05:06
```

EDIT:

In your sample are mising escaping chars `\` and is possible use instead `\d+` `[0-9]+`:

```
df['Time'].replace('\([0-9]+\)\s*','', regex=True, inplace=True)
print (df)
                 Time
0  5/10/2017 01:05:03
1  5/11/2017 04:05:06
```

Comment: Awesome, that works!  Could you describe the backslash and d+ values in str.replace() and how they're used, or if there's documentation on how you came up with that input? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately regex problematic is very huge, in pandas documentation are only some samples [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extract-first-match-in-each-subject-extract) - it is about extracting, but similar works with `str.replace`.